# Nginx peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking

Tags: nginx

I got this error message when configured SSL in nginx.

> *15 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking, client: 98.158.245.100, server: 0.0.0.0:443
> Below is my SSL config file:

```
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name  mydomain.cn;

    ssl_certificate      D:/Applications/nginx-1.15.6/ssl/esign/mydomain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  D:/Applications/nginx-1.15.6/ssl/esign/mydomain.key;

    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    
    default_type 'text/html';

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://153.152.123.492;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check if your upstream server has the certificate as well.

check the clients protocols because you provide support only for TLSv1.2
pass some more headers to your upstream

try

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

try adding support for http2 to eliminate continues handshaking if nginx was compiled with it, like so

```
listen  443 ssl http2;
```

it would be helpfull though looking at your upstream logs as well, maybe for a 502